# Using Sentri lanes as a UK Citizen with Global Entry

Tags: uk, uk-citizens, global-entry, sentri

I am a British (UK) citizen currently living in Mexico with permanent residency status in Mexico. I have a B2 visa for the US and was recently approved for the Global Entry program. I plan to use the Global Entry lines at US airports when flying to/from the UK but also plan to use the Sentri/Global Entry lane when driving from Mexico into the USA.

My understanding is that as a British Citizen (UK) i do not get issued a Global Entry card despite being a member of the program. Will i be able to drive in the Sentri/Global Entry lane when crossing the land border from Mexico into the US as i am a Global Entry member, but cannot be issued a card?

Answer (score 1):

You may not use the lanes without the card, as the card contains electronics which tell US Customs that the vehicle and passengers are allowed to use it. See the following from the US Customs & Border Control's [FAQ page regarding Global Entry](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions):

> **Must I obtain a Global Entry card?**
>
> No, it is not necessary to obtain a Global Entry card to continue
>   using Global Entry at airport kiosks. A card is only required for
>   expedited entry at the SENTRI and NEXUS lanes coming into the United
>   States.

I'm assuming that you applied for Global Entry as a Mexican national? It doesn't appear that UK nationals can apply for Global Entry:

> **Can I join Global Entry if I am not a U.S. citizen or U.S. lawful
>   permanent resident?**
>
> Global Entry is also available to citizens of the Netherlands who are
>   enrolled in FLUX and Korean Smart Entry Service members. Citizens of
>   Germany, Panama, and Mexico may also apply for Global Entry. Canadian
>   NEXUS members have Global Entry benefits, but are not eligible to
>   join.

If so, you [should be able to get a card](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/card):

> Global Entry cards are issued to Global entry members who are U.S.
>   citizens, U.S. lawful permanent residents and Mexican nationals.

It takes a bit of time for a card to arrive in the mail after approval, but if you're sure you didn't get sent one, you can request one for $15 from within your TTP profile

Though, even after jumping through all those hoops, it probably isn't worth it if you're only crossing once, as you also need to register your vehicle with CPB and have them inspect it prior to using the lane:

> Global Entry members who wish to drive their vehicle in the SENTRI
>   lanes, must register their vehicle with CBP and schedule an
>   appointment at a SENTRI enrollment center to conduct a 7-point vehicle
>   inspection.